# System crack with Task C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = true;
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            a = getBoolean();
        });
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        });
        while (!t.IsCompleted)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("initial : a = {0}", a);
        }
        if (a == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From system a = {0}", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From system a = {0}", false);
        }
    }

    public static bool getBoolean()
    {
        Task<bool> a = DelayTask();
        bool r = a.Result;
        a.Dispose();
        return r;
    }

    public static Task<bool> DelayTask()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Once I run this code above my windows dies automatically.  (I have to press power button in my laptop). Can some one help me to reproduce this problem and give me an explanation for why this happens.

Comment: Single-core system? You're busy waiting.

Comment: No..i have 4 core in my laptop - core i3

Comment: once you press any key...system crack..??? and I don't know why.

Comment: Nothing in this code is directly causing this. Probably the CPU consumption triggers an anomaly in the rest of the system. Comment out the busy waiting, or replace the entire program with `while(true);` to confirm.

Comment: Laptop, maybe overheating from busy waiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from

```
while (!t.IsCompleted)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("initial : a = {0}", a);
}
```

You are doing nothing inside that loop, it is causing 100% of a single core's CPU useage, if you are on a single core machine this most defiantly could cause it to lock up.

On a multi-core machine it may cause significant slowness, but it should not cause a total system lockup. You could have something else going wrong in your system and the heat or system load caused by this program may cause some other part of the computer to fail causing the lockup.

The quick solution is put some kind of sleep in there to release the CPU

```
while (!t.IsCompleted)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); //Sleep for 100ms for the next check
}
```

or even better, replace the whole loop with

```
t.Wait();
```

However there are MANY other things you are doing that are considered "not good coding practices" and the entire program likely needs a re-write.

Comment: Thank @Scott Chamberlain. I just try to understand behavior of TPL only. But it so crazy because I think I can do 2 task at same time. One - Consoler.Readline() and other do some stuff..???